# Update the status in table from "reserved" to "expired" using the datagridview value in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, cell-formatting

Good day sir. I am working on a datagridview where I want that it to automatically update the its row together with database table status from "reserved" to "expired" whenever it exceeds the expiry date.
i am using the `DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs` to determine the condition and to update the database. Here is my code:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {if (DateTime.Now.Date > Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[7].Value).Date ))
            {
                        con = new SqlConnection(conString);
                        string query = "UPDATE tblReservation SET Status='expired'";
                        cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
            }
        }
```

but whenever i execute this codes. It sets all the status of the table to "expired". What is proper way or proper events that be used to resolve this problem?.

Thank in advance for the help.

Comment: add a where clause to your update query. Which field in that row holds the primary key for the table tblReservation?

Comment: because you did not specify `where clause` in your query that is why it is updating all Status to expired

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a WHERE clause in your sql statement like @rene suggested in his comment.

Sql statement example:

```
UPDATE tblReservation 
SET Status='expired' 
WHERE reservationId = row.Cells[***the row id index should come here***].Value;
```